# super mysterious logic error for a planar fitting image processing algorithm

Tags: c++, image-processing, bmp

so i have this image processing program where i am using a linear regression algorithm to find a plane that best fits all of the points (x,y,z: z being the pixel color intensity (0-255)

Simply speaking i have this picture of  ? x ? dimension. I run this algorithm and i get these A, B, C values. (3 float values)

then i go every pixel in the program and minus the pixel value with mod_val where

mod_val = (-A * x -B * y ) / C

A,B,C are constants while x,y is the pixel location in a x,y plane.

When the dimension of the picture is divisible by 100 its perfect but when its not the picture fractures. The picture itself is the same as the original but there is a diagonal line with color contrast that goes across the picture. The program is supposed to make the pixel color uniform from the center.

I tried running the picture where mod_val = 0 for not divisble by 100 dimension pictures and it copies a new picture perfectly. So i doubt there is a problem with storing and writing the read data in terms of alignment. (fyi this picture is a grey scale 8 bit.bmp)

I have tried changing the A,B,C values but the diagonal remains the same. The color of the image fragments within the diagonals change.

when i run 1400 x 1100 picture it works perfectly with the mod_val equation written above which is the most baffling part.

I spent a lot of time looking for rounding errors. They are virtually all floats. The dimension i used for breaking picture is 1490 x 1170.

here is a gragment of the code where i think a error is occuring:

```
    int img_row = row_length;
    int img_col = col_length;
    int i = 0;
    float *pfAmultX = new float[img_row];
    for (int x = 0; x < img_row; x++)
    {
        pfAmultX[x] = (A * x)/C;
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < img_col; y++)
    {
        float BmultY = B*y/C;
        for (int x = 0; x < img_row; x++, i++)
        {
            modify_val = pfAmultX[x] + BmultY;
            int temp = (int) data.data[i];
            data.data[i] += (unsigned char) modify_val; 
            if(temp >= 250){
                data.data[i] = 255;
            }
            else if(temp < 0){
                data.data[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    delete[] pfAmultX;
```

The img_row, img_col is correct according to VS debugger mode

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to find this bug for many hours now and my boss is telling me that i can't go back home until i find this bug.....

before algorithm (1400 x 1100, works)
[image: imgur.com/pBCBzdH]
after
[image: imgur.com/KiG6Jx2]

before (1490 x 1170, demonstrates the problem)
[image: imgur.com/zSRUdJi]
after
[image: imgur.com/eXvef88]

UPDATE:
well i have boiled down the problem as something with the x coordinate after extensive testing.

This is because when i use large A or B values or both (C value is always ~.999) for 1400x1100 it does not create diagonals.

However, for the other image, large B values do not create diagonals but a fairly small - avg A value creates diagonals.

Whats even more, when i test a picture where x is disivible by 100 but y is divisible by 10. the answer is correct.

Comment: Can you post four pictures: 1) before, 2) after not showing the error (dimensions are divisible by 100), 3) before, 4) after showing the error?

Comment: i would like to but i can't because i need alteast 10 reputation....

Comment: Upload them to a site like imgur and link to them from your question. I can edit them to be directly shown after that.

Comment: before algorithm (1400 x 1100)
http://imgur.com/pBCBzdH
after 
http://imgur.com/KiG6Jx2

before (1490 x 1170)
http://imgur.com/zSRUdJi
after
http://imgur.com/eXvef88

Comment: Is it possible the bug is where you determine the constants A, B and C? For example, what were the A, B and C for image 1 and 2 in your question?

Comment: well i also tried a test where i resized a identical image and i used the A,B,C that was identical to the 1400x1100 but still created diagonals none the less. The shades of darkness for inside the diagonals were different very slightly however. I've also tried making mod_val = 10 for example and the whole image uniformly changed color.

Comment: also for the 1400 x 1100 image. when i change A,B,C to arbitrary values it does messes up the uniformity of the color but does not create sharp contrasting diagonals

Comment: when i put in arbitrary values for 1400 x 1100 A,B,C the color gets messed up but no diagonals. For the 1490x1170 the case is the same for the B value but a very small number for the A value will start creating diagonals. which does not happen for images that is divible by 100

Comment: What are the values of A, B and C used to generate the broken image?

Comment: -.0058 and -.0058 the thing is though when i put in the same A and B into 2 different images where its 1400 x 1100 or 1300 x 1020 it creates no diagonals. It is good to note that all three images are resized version of the same image so they look exceptionally similar. The latter two worked without a hitch

Comment: Is it possibly a `float` to `int` problem? I can't see the types of your `A, B, C` but try making the `float` explicit, like this line `float BmultY = (float)B * (float)y/C` - do similar for other instances.

Comment: well the A,B,C variables are originally float values. But like you said i tried casting everything explicitly but still no luck...

Comment: Ok, one other thing, you're casting `modify_val` to `unsigned char` - is it possible that this is overflowing?

Comment: mmmmm overflowing as in the number is too big? Because the values for modify_val has a lot of decimals but the value itself is not very large. I think the largest number is when modify_val is 11 or something like that. Just in case i made a temp where i casted the float to int and using that temp to convert to unsigned char but still diagonals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well in the end i found the solution. It was a problem due to the padding the the bitmap. When the dimension on the x was not divisible by 4 it would use padding which would throw off all of the x coordinates. This also meant that the row_value i received from the bmp header was the same as the dimension but not really the same in reality. I had to make a edit where i had to do: 4 * (row_value_from_bmp_header + 3)/ 4.

Comment: Sounds like a nasty bug :)

Comment: it was. I went home at 3:40 am and only got to go home cause my boss caught it after looking at it with me for 2 hours after i looked at it for 8 and having no luck.....

Comment: This is a well known problem with BMP files. Sorry I didn't see this question earlier.